# Fully Remove Google Voice Search

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google, lg-g3, google-voice-actions

I am running Lollipop on the LG G3 and due to a loose connection on the audio jack google voice search gets activated everytime a slight movement of ANY attached cable.

Now, I would like to deactivate google voice search completely. My phone is rooted and i am willing to raze any part of the file system to stop this annoying hellfire.

It is annoying because I can be on a free-hands call and google voice search asks me over the speakers "In order to do a google voice search please unlock your phone".

Additionally, the same physical problem results on the default music player starting to play music. Is there a wat to deactivate the wire control for the music player ?

Answer (score 1):

- Open your Google app (not chrome).
- Press "more"
- On the new screen press "settings"
- You should see "google assistant" and "voice", press "voice"
- Press "voice match" under the"ok Google" section.
- You have finally reached the screen you need. Here turn of the setting "access with voice match"

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple to just remove the app, I've done this on many devices without issue.

I recommend using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). Just find voice search in its app list, tap it, and choose uninstall.